# Using sed to give current date in mm/dd/YYYY format?

Tags: date

So I know that in order to replace something with the current date it would be

```
sed "s/something/`date +"%m-%d-%Y"`/" file.txt
```

This would give me the date in mm-dd-YYYY
But I want to be able the get the date in mm/dd/YYYY

Comment: What do you mean by proper format? What is the exact command you are running and what is the expected output supposed to look like? Please consider [editing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/545988/edit) your post to include more context. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, please clarify. Do you mean `m/d/y` as you have in the question title? Shouldn't that be `mm/dd/yy`? Or perhaps `mm/dd/yyyy`? Please [edit] your question and add an example showing a specific date.

Answer (score 2):

'/' has by default a special meaning for sed, so you need to either escape the '/' like this:

```
sed "s/something/`date +"%m\/%d\/%Y"`/" file.txt
```

or use another separator for sed, like this and there is no need to escape the '/':

```
sed "s|something|`date +"%m/%d/%Y"`|" file.txt
```

Comment: I'd still recommend you use the more modern `$( ... )` construct instead of backticks.